# Reading lines with a lot of spaces and maintaining them in output

Tags: bash, while-loop, tabs, space

i have a file that looks like this, but a lot bigger :

```
xxxxxxx                                              xxxxx                 xxxx
yyyyyyy                                              yyyyy                 yyyy
zzzzzzz                                              zzzzz                 zzzz
bbbbbbb                                                                    bbbb
```

but a lot bigger, i want to compare the second and the third column, only the first 4 digits do i wrote something like this :

```
while IFS='' read -r line; do

a=${line:181:4}
b=${line:276:4}
str1="$a"
str2="$b"

# echo $a
# echo $b
# echo $str1
# echo $str2

if [[ "$str1" == "$str2" ]]
then

      echo $line >> $1.diffs.txt
fi

done <$1
```

the reason for the str* is because the numbers occasionally start with 0 so it interprets them as octal and gives me an error, my problem is that the output on the $1.diffs.txt contains only 1 white space, instead of all of them. IE

Output :

```
xxxxxxx                                              xxxxx              xxxx
yyyyyyy                                              yyyyy                 yyyy
zzzzzzz                                              zzzzz                 zzzz
```

Comment: In your `if` statement, you need to quote `$line` i.e. `echo "$line" >> ...` to preserve the whitespace

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk` in place of your existing shell script:

```
awk '{ if (substr($2,0,4) == substr($3,0,4)) { print $0 }}' $1 > $1.diffs.txt
```

`awk` separates on whitespaces by default, so you can do your comparison with the variables `$2` and `$3` instead of having to manually define the substring positions

Comment: my problem is that column 2 is not always full, sometimes its just blanks, i wonder if awk will "hit" an error on that!

Comment: Yes it would. You should update your question to make it clearer, this situation was not mentioned.